# django.db.utils.IntegrityError(could not create unique index)

Tags: django-models, uuid

When am trying to add new Unique_id (uuid) field in the existing django models , It returns the intgerity error.

```
models.py:
     class Directory(models.Model):

    unique_id =   models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name    =    models.CharField(max_length=120)
    path    =    models.CharField(max_length=240)

Views.py:
def get_dir_dict(request, dir):
    dir_info['pk']       = query.pk
    dir_info['unique_id']  = query.unique_id
    dir_info['name']     = query.name
    dir_info['path']     = query.path


error:
File "/home/sitharth/zeal/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "zkloud_directory_unique_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (unique_id)=(734e8926-386b-47a9-9ac0-d617f45f7113) is duplicated.
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem any solutions??

Comment: I am going to ping this a year later. I am still having this problem with django 3.1

Comment: I would give this solution a try: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields It solved my issue of creating a migration with a unique field